# Database Design for a status update system involving companies and users

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am having an issue that involves a differentiation between whether a status update belongs to a user or a company. Let me explain: Individuals can post statuses as a user or as a company. A user can be a member/owner of a company and switch to a company in the dashboard much like Facebook. The problem is: how will we set in the database whether a status was posted by a company or by a user?

My solution was to have a company column that was a Boolean variable and when we query for each status to display we check if it was from a company. If so then we grab the company_id and look up the name and other relevant information in the database and display it on the site. Does this sound like the right approach? Additionally, does the schema below look correct?

```
**Company**
id int(11)
name varchar (255)

**Company_members**
company_id int(11) FK_Company
user_id int(11) FK_Users
owner BOOLEAN

**Users**
id int(11)
name varchar (255)

**Status**
id
date DATETIME
user_id  FK_Users
company_id FK_Company
company BOOLEAN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema looks good, but the company boolean in the Status table seems redundant. You can just set the company_id to NULL when the status is for an individual's account, and then query `SELECT * from Status WHERE company_id IS NULL` to get individuals' statuses, and `SELECT * FROM Status WHERE company_id IS NOT NULL` to get companies' statuses.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Party Model. You need to use table inheritance. Single Table inheritance is simpler and faster but may use nulls.

```
create table party_type (
  id int primary key,
  description text not null unique
);

insert into party_type values
(1, 'Individual'),
(2, 'Organization');

create table party (
  id serial primary key,
  type int not null references party_type(id),
  name text not null
);

create table status_update(
  id serial primary key,
  date datetime,
  party_id not null references party(id)
);
```

(syntax is postgres but you should be able to translate to mysql easily)